# Binary to Decimal For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, bin

Hi I am a new programmer and I trying to complete one my assignments which requires to me convert a binary number to a denary one. I am not getting any errors however i dont get the correct denary equivalent, please help. This is what i've done so far.

```
binary = "10111"
denary = 0
length=len(binary)
for i in range(length-1,-1,-1):
   if binary[i] == "1":
    denary += (2**i)
else:
    denary += 0
print(denary)
```

and the output is:

```
29
```

Comment: The problem is that `i` will corresponding to the decimal digit in the reversed order...

Comment: I suppose that your assignment doesn't let you use `int(binary, 2)`?

Comment: @dan04 yes, we were told not use that

Comment: @usr2564301 no, i just needed it for python 3, sorry for tagging python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're coming from the wrong direction. You can use `binary[::-1]` or `reversed(binary)` to reverse the array.

```
binary = "10111"
denary = 0

for i, d in enumerate(reversed(binary)):
    if d == "1":
        denary += (2**i)

print(denary)
```

---

Also note that you can do this:

```
denary = int(binary, 2)  # Parses string on base 2 to integer base 10

print(denary)
```

Comment: Nice and simple, although `enumerate(reversed(binary))` is, in my opinion, more readable. (It also looks to be about 20% faster.)

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Thank you for the hint. Going to include it in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reverse list like this:

```
binary = "10111" # needs to be reversed so the lowest bit is in front for ease of computing
denary = 0

# ind = index,  bit = the bitvalue as string of the reversed string 
for ind, bit in enumerate(binary[::-1]): # reversed copy of string
    denary += int(bit)*2**ind  # if bit is 0 this evaluates to 0, else to the  power of 2
print(denary)
```